# C# Office Outlook VSTO addin does not update after changes in code

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I have a strange issue with my addin updates.
I don't see any changes I made to the addin since previous debug session - I've changed few things on the ribbon and addin behavior as well.
When I go to the debugging session, it starts Outlook with addin in the previous version... no changes at all.

What I already tried:

1. Removing addin from the COM list in Outlook
2. Rebuilding solution
3. Removing registry entries at HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Office/Outlook/Addins/

with no luck.
I don't know where to look next - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you develop a VSTO based add-in you need to use the `Clean` command from the Visual Studio context menu to unregister the add-in. The host application should be closed at this time.

Most probably you have installed the add-in using the add-in installer and also registered it from Visual Studio. That's why you could see an old add-in version. I'd suggest checking windows registry keys for your add-in first. See [Registry entries for VSTO Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/registry-entries-for-vsto-add-ins?view=vs-2019) for more information.